# Is it possible to alternate z-index on CSS animation

Tags: css, z-index, keyframe

I have been trying this multiple ways with no success.  JavaScript, TweenLite, etc. I need to alternate two `<div>` tags, **slide1** & **slide2**, that live inside **slide**. Fading one out to fading one in.  A continuous loop.  I can use a basic css `@keyframes` animation like bellow.  It works fine, but they are clickable links and one `<div>` will always remain on top.

Is there a way to loop the z-index of each div in the `@keyframes` anim?

Or maybe a completely better method?

**CSS**

```
.slider {
  max-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.slide1,.slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide1 {
animation:fade 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade 8s infinite;

} 
.slide2 {
animation:fade2 8s infinite;
-webkit-animation:fade2 8s infinite;
}
@keyframes fade
{
  0%   {opacity:1}
  33.333% { opacity: 0}
  66.666% { opacity: 0}
  100% { opacity: 1}
}
@keyframes fade2
{
  0%   {opacity:0}
  33.333% { opacity: 1}
  66.666% { opacity: 0 }
  100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide1"></div>
    <div class="slide2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put a demo somewhere, like on [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/) and paste the link here.

Comment: Include your html markup.

Comment: Ok included HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They seem to be working for me, check it out: https://codepen.io/giovannipds/pen/LzgYaa

```
<style>
  .slider {
    line-height: 1.5;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
  }
  .slide {
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .slide,
  .slide a {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .slide1 {
    animation: fade 8s infinite;
    background: red;
  }
  .slide2 {
    animation: fade2 8s infinite;
    background: blue;
  }
  @keyframes fade
  {
    0% { opacity: 1 ; z-index: 2; }
    33.333% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1; }
    66.666% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 1; z-index: 2; }
  }
  @keyframes fade2
  {
    0% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1; }
    33.333% { opacity: 1; z-index: 2; }
    66.666% { opacity: 1; z-index: 2; }
    100% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1; }
  }
</style>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide slide1">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="//www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a></li>
      <li><a href="//www.globo.com" target="_blank">Globo.com</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="slide slide2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="//www.lovemondays.com.br" target="_blank">Love Mondays</a></li>
      <li><a href="//www.hotmail.com" target="_blank">Hotmail</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep this works great.  So I can just add z-index into the @keyframes markup! Excellent...Thank you  And thank you for making the HTML

Comment: One thing before you go.  I noticed its popping.  Im not good enough to see the problem yet.  I wanted it to transition between them clean with a good 8sec delay.  What do you think?

Comment: @NodeCodeMan using this technique, you're gonna have to decide how much time will be designated to the animation + 8 sec to the delay. You can acquire that by playing with the percentages (because you're not allowed to define time in seconds in keyframes), something like 0% -> 10% -> 90% -> 100%. Get it?

Comment: Hey sorry I just posted another question about this, with your code before I saw you wrote back.  I do kinda get it. The % are just difficult to see.  A timeline would be so much easier.

Comment: Actually this may not be working correctly.  I just noticed its the z-index change that is causing the transition not to be clean.  If you remove it works great.

Comment: @NewCodeMan well, that I don't know. You realize that you're kind of trying to use something that's not its purpose, right? I guess you should rely on JavaScript, it is better for this kind of purpose. Maybe you can try to have fun with [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/transitionend) to deal with `z-index`, but I guess it'll probably work the same way, worth a test.